# Parar un metódo que se ejecuta 2 veces

Tags: c#

Estoy creando un programa que recibe datos de 2 lectores QR los cuales me ejecutan un metodo para realizar unas operaciones matematicas segun los datos recibidos.

Mi problema viene porque la lectura de los lectores QR se me ejecuta a la vez y con ello el metodo de los calculos.

```
com2.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(CodigoEnvases);
com6.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(CodigoEnvases);
```

Como se podría hacer para que si ya se ejecuto "CodigoEnvases", este no se vuelva a ejecutar.

Perdon si no me explique bien, es la primera vez que recurro a esto. Gracias.

Comment: Usa un flag para que solo se ejecute una vez.. entras, controlas el flag.. si esta apagado, lo prendes y ejecutas y lo apagas al final.. si esta prendido, salis directamente...

Answer (score 0):

Que yo sepa suponiendo que es todo sincrónico tienes la siguiente manera.

1. lock que blockea el código de dentro para que vaya uno a la vez el otro se espera hasta que acabe el otro

   ```
   object _lock;

   function void CodigoEnvases(){


    lock(_lock)
    {
      //Código función

    }

    }
   ```